# Debugging in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, debugging, vuejs2

How to debug Vue App? I am using Chrome extension named "Vue.js devtools". 
But I would like to trace execution flow. How can I do that ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to trace? You can try [Chrome DevTools' Async Stack Trace](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/) feature...

Comment: Also you can trace Events (clicks, submit, etc) and Vuex actions through [Vue Devtools extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)

Answer (score -3):

Take advantage of Chrome extensions

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Good Day!

Comment: Aside from the fact that this is a link only answer, the question mentions specifically already using Vue Devtools.